# Path inserted into sys.path but import module still shows error, what am I missing?

Tags: python, import, module, path

[image]

[image]Does anyone know the proper way to import a module in a different directory?
I have used the following codes below, it works but there is still a 'no module named ...' error.
The code runs fine but I do not know how to get the import to recognise the file.

```
import sys

path = r'C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Documents\Programming\Python'
sys.path.insert(0, path)  # insert file path to the start of the path list

import random100Numbers  # Here there is a no module named warning...

print(random100Numbers.rand100Num(90))  # code executes as it is
print(random100Numbers.rand100Num(-100))  # code executes as it is
```

Comment: This question is confusing.  You say the code "works", but it still has a "no module named" error.  Those things cannot both be true.

Comment: Post the full warning so that we'll better understand your "problem". Paraphrasing or truncating the message does not help.

Comment: @JohnGordon Please see the added screenshots. The IDE is still showing a red underlined error 'No module named' error but it is able to compile and execute the function written correctly. Are you able to explain how this is happening?

Comment: @JustinEzequiel I have posted the screenshots for your reference. Are you able to deduce what I am missing that would cause the warning?

Comment: That's not a python problem. That's an IDE issue.